# Plutus Pioneer Week 2 Smart Contracts

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

Do I need to run the `cabal build` for all the weekly modules? Will it do the following for all of the modules? Please confirm.

```
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-ledger-api-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - cardano-ledger-alonzo-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - ouroboros-consensus-shelley-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - ouroboros-consensus-cardano-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - cardano-api-1.27.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-ledger-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-chain-index-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-contract-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - playground-common-0.1.0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - plutus-pioneer-program-week02-0.1.0.0 (lib) (first run)
Starting     plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Building     plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Installing   plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Completed    plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Starting     plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Building     plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Installing   plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Completed    plutus-tx-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Starting     plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Starting     plutus-ledger-api-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Building     plutus-ledger-api-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Building     plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Installing   plutus-ledger-api-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Installing   plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Completed    plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Completed    plutus-ledger-api-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Starting     cardano-ledger-alonzo-0.1.0.0 (lib)
Building     cardano-ledger-alonzo-0.1.0.0 (lib)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we need to run `cabal build` for all weekly modules to build it. It will download the packages which seems a repetitive process.

Comment: You can also use the Plutus Playground as well, which I personally found easier.

Answer (score 0):

All the weekly modules need an update as they use the latest (and thus different) Plutus commits. I wouldn't know the exact files that require rebuilding as I use *nix-shell* followed by *cabal* and so update and rebuild is all done seamlessly.

The reason that such frequent updates are required is that there is still a lot of change taking place in the Plutus code base. This is expected to change once Plutus has gone live (September) and there is a stable live version.